React Native with Typescript still showing previously logged in user after new login
I'm building a React Native with Typescript app that requires users to log in, but the problem I'm facing is that when a user logs out and another user logs in, it still shows the previous users details from AsyncStorage.
I'd appreciate the help figuring out what the issue is. Below is my 'LoginScreen' component:
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image, Switch } from 'react-native';
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { router } from 'expo-router';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import * as React from 'react'


export default function LoginScreen() {
  

  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
    },
    
  });

  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    fetch("API", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(async (response) => {
        if (response.status === "success") {
       //  localStorage.setItem("email", JSON.stringify(data));

       await AsyncStorage.setItem('email',JSON.stringify(data));
  
        router.replace('./home');
        } else {
          setText('Email address not found')
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };


  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false)
  const switchDefaultColor = "#ff00ff"
  const primaryColor = "#dd00dd"

  const toggleSwitch = async () => {
    const updated = !isEnabled
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('enableBiometric', updated.toString());
    setIsEnabled(updated);
  };

  const printSomething = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('enableBiometric');
      console.log(value);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
     AsyncStorage.getItem('enableBiometric').then((value) => {
       const enableBiometric = value === "true" ? true : false
       setIsEnabled(enableBiometric)
       setIsLoaded(true);
       
     });
  }, [])

  if(isLoaded === false ) {
    return null
  }

  {isEnabled ? 
    router.replace('./fingerprint') : 
     router.replace('./login')}
 


  return (
    <><View style={styles.main}>
       <View style={{ width: "100%", position: "absolute", top: 20,   justifyContent: 'center', 
  alignItems: 'center', }}>
      <Image
      source={require('@/assets/images/shield.png')}
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={styles.reactLogo} />

<Text style={styles.headingtext}>Log in to audiesafe</Text>
</View>
  
<View style={{ width: "85%", position: "absolute", top: 300 }}>

<Text style={{marginLeft: 6, fontSize: 16, color: "red", marginBottom: 4}}>
{text}
      </Text>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name={"email"}
          render={({ field: { value, onChange, onBlur } }) => (
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Enter email address"
              style={styles.input}
              value={value}
              onChangeText={onChange}
              onBlur={onBlur}
              placeholderTextColor="lightgrey" />
          )} />


        
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: "center", fontWeight: 500, fontSize: 16 }}>Continue</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
        </View>
     </>
  )
}


